# How to expand a list comprehension with two foor loops in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

Given the following code from Leetcode:

```
def combine(self, n: int, k: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    combs = [[]]
    for _ in range(k):
        combs = [[i] + c for c in combs for i in range(1, c[0] if c else n+1)]
    return combs
```

How would one go about expanding the inner `combs` loop for readablity? I attempted below but I'm getting errors about indexing out of bounds with the `c[0]` part so I know I'm doing something wrong, but I couldn't find one that was quite similar enough for this in similar list comprehension questions to know what I'm actually doing incorrectly.

```
for c in combs:
            if c:
                for i in range(1, c[0]):
                    combs.extend([i] + c)
            else:
                for i in range(1, n+1):
                    combs.extend([i] + c)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: it is not a good idea to manipulate inside a loop whatever is being looped over. In the for loop case the `combs` is extended while it is being looped over. If you look closely, that does not happen in the list comprehension example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list comprehension in itself is quite readable once you get used to them. For instance, I would prefer it, but would add at least one line break there. And consistent spaces around '+'.

```
def combine(self, n: int, k: int) -> List[List[int]]:
  combs = [[]]
  for _ in range(k):
    combs = [[i] + c for c in combs 
             for i in range(1, c[0] if c else n + 1)]
  return combs
```

To help understand it better, this is the equivalent with for loops, which I suppose you are after:

```
def combine2(n: int, k: int):
    combs = [[]]
    for _ in range(k):
        tmp_combs = []
        for c in combs:
            for i in range(1, c[0] if c else n + 1):
                tmp_combs.append([i] + c)

        combs = tmp_combs
    return combs
```

Also, although the results are same from these two functions, they have some difference in performance. List comprehensions are a bit faster, especially for simple operations as shown in this [post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/list-comprehension-python-always-faster-than-alex-falkovskiy).

Comment: I see, this makes much more sense! Obviously I'm relatively new to list comprehensions beyond the basics but this clears things up. Thanks!